OpenDDS Security - Permission allow rule does not seem to apply
I use OpenDDS 3.29.1 using ACE 8.0.1. on a windows machine.
Security features are enabled, and I am trying to set up the governance and permission files in such a way that it only allows a specific list of topics per participant, based on user's certificate.
The permission file looks like below.
Regardless of which topics I allow in the <allow_rule> (even when I use wildcards to cover everything), OpenDDS resorts to the default action which is to DENY access.
One interesting thing I observe is that if I try to define the topics that are denied
using the <deny_rule>, and assuming a default action of ALLOW, that that works as expected, with the log message indicating that I had a hit within the <deny_rule> list.
Is this a bug with the OpenDDS library or am I misconfiguring the permissions?
Thanks
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<dds xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="OpenDDS/omg_shared_ca_permissions.xsd">
    <permissions>
        <grant name="MPPermission">
            <subject_name>C=Op,ST=OpenDDS,L=OpenDDS,O=OpenDDS,OU=OpenDDS,CN=mp</subject_name>
            <validity>
                <!-- Format is CCYY-MM-DDThh:mm:ss[Z|(+|-)hh:mm] in GMT -->
                <not_before>2015-09-15T01:00:00</not_before>
                <not_after>2025-09-15T01:00:00</not_after>
            </validity>
            <allow_rule>
                <domains>
                    <id_range>
                        <min>1</min>
                        <max>100</max>
                    </id_range>
                </domains>
                <publish>
                    <topics>
                        <topic>TopicA</topic>
                    </topics>
                </publish>
                <subscribe>
                    <topics>
                        <topic>TopicB</topic>
                    </topics>
                </subscribe>
            </allow_rule>
            <deny_rule>
                <domains>
                    <id_range>
                        <min>1</min>
                        <max>100</max>
                    </id_range>
                </domains>
                <publish>
                    <topics>
                        <topic>TopicC</topic>
                    </topics>
                </publish>
                <subscribe>
                    <topics>
                        <topic>TopicD</topic>
                    </topics>
                </subscribe>
            </deny_rule>
            <default>DENY</default>
        </grant>
    </permissions>
</dds>


It looks correct at a glance, so I will try this out myself. This might be an obvious question, but just to make sure, your domain id(s) are somewhere in the range of 1-100, correct?

yes the domain IDs are fine. I double checked by using an invalid domain ID and it works as expected. the issue seems to be that it does not find any topics under the <allow_rule> but it does under the <deny_rule> .

I copied the file into tests/DCPS/Messenger/permissions_1.xml (publisher) in OpenDDS, enabled write access in governance, resigned the files, renamed the topic name to TopicA in the publisher and it worked for me. If I changed the publisher topic to anything else, it gave me a  'No matching rule for topic" as expected. A couple of other thoughts: What is the exact setup of the topics? The permissions you showed would only work on one side. Maybe they're mixed up?

Another possible issue is do the topic names you're actually trying to use have special characters in them? If they do they could be interpreted in the permissions files as wildcard expressions: https://opendds.readthedocs.io/en/latest-release/devguide/annex.html#fnmatch-exprs

Regarding the mix-up of topics, the app does not even get a chance to exchange any messages. I do not use the OpenDDS API directly, rather there is an abstraction layer in between, so in my case when the OpenDDS APi fails to create a read/write the whole app exits. And there are no special characters in the topic names, just letters. What I find weird is that I get a no match, even when I use wildcards. Can it be any of the other flags in the governance file?

And here is the exact error I get "Permissions check failed for local datawriter on topic 'TopicA'. Security Exception[-1.0]: AccessControlBuiltInImpl: No matching rule for topic, default permission is DENY."

The solution to the issue is to also define the partition the users are part of as part of the <allow_rule>. Alternatively, you can use wildcards to allow all partitions. The complete permission file looks like this
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<dds xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="OpenDDS/omg_shared_ca_permissions.xsd">
    <permissions>
        <grant name="MPPermission">
            <subject_name>C=Op,ST=OpenDDS,L=OpenDDS,O=OpenDDS,OU=OpenDDS,CN=mp</subject_name>
            <validity>
                <!-- Format is CCYY-MM-DDThh:mm:ss[Z|(+|-)hh:mm] in GMT -->
                <not_before>2015-09-15T01:00:00</not_before>
                <not_after>2025-09-15T01:00:00</not_after>
            </validity>
            <allow_rule>
                <domains>
                    <id_range>
                        <min>1</min>
                        <max>100</max>
                    </id_range>
                </domains>
                <publish>
                    <topics>
                        <topic>TopicA</topic>
                    </topics>
                    <partitions>
                        <partition>*</partition>
                    </partitions>
                </publish>
                <subscribe>
                    <topics>
                        <topic>TopicB</topic>
                    </topics>
                    <partitions>
                        <partition>*</partition>
                    </partitions>
                </subscribe>
            </allow_rule>
            <deny_rule>
                <domains>
                    <id_range>
                        <min>1</min>
                        <max>100</max>
                    </id_range>
                </domains>
                <publish>
                    <topics>
                        <topic>TopicC</topic>
                    </topics>
                </publish>
                <subscribe>
                    <topics>
                        <topic>TopicD</topic>
                    </topics>
                </subscribe>
            </deny_rule>
            <default>DENY</default>
        </grant>
    </permissions>
</dds>


It's great you figured it out. I'm still curious why it worked for me. Are you using partitions?

If so, maybe we could improve the error/warning message to give me information about what didn't match.

I do use partition and probably that is why a part ion wildcard is required to find a matching rule. Interestly enough, but that only affects the allow_rule. What might help is to modify the exist log message that indicates the was no rule match for a specific topic, but to include any other attributes (such as partition, domain, etc)  that the filter is using so it become s clear what info is missing
